# Is it correct to define a function this way?

Tags: functions

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},f(x)=\begin{cases} x+1 & x\le-1 \\ 2x+2 & x>1 \end{cases}$

The domain of definition is $\mathbb{R}$ but the function is not defined on $(-1;1]$.

The problem asks to specify whether the function is injective or not.

If the function is simply not defined on $(-1;1]$ then in my opinion it is injective but if it is randomly defined for example $x^2-1$ then it is not injective.

Is this a mathematical mistake in my textbook?

Comment: Likely a typo...

Comment: Probably a typo.

Comment: Yes, the definition in the book is wrong. But it could be a just a typo.

Comment: Probably there is a typo, it should be $2x+2$ for $x>-1$

Comment: Thanks guys. It's weird that there's one more problem with such a typo. People are really too lazy to check things.

Comment: Or its a partial function. But that's unlikely in math calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a mistake in the book. In the notation $f:A\to B$, the set $A$ is the domain of $f$, i.e. the collection of numbers for which $f$ is defined. Your  book should specify what $f(x)$ equals when $-1<x\le1$, but it doesn't, meaning that $f$ is not well-defined. As mentioned in the comments, it is likely there was a typo in the book.

Note: although every member of $A$ is associated with a member of $B$, it is not necessarily true that every member of $B$ is associated with a member of $A$. The image of $f$ is always a subset of $B$ (though it might not be a *proper* subset). For example, if $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, then it is perfectly valid to say that $f$ is a function from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$, even though the image of $f$ is $[0,\infty)$.